# Solution for the initial JS process on a webpage that should be done each time the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend

I have a huge DOM in my HTML file and a lot of elements that are manipulated by JavaScript each time the page is loaded.

These processes take time (not only the queries but also the manipulation processes) and it is not logical to do it every time.

The only way I figured out is to get the manipulated DOM created by JS from the browser DevTools and replace it with my original DOM. But I have to do it after each change on my file.

I would accept exporting the executed DOM after each change as the solution to this problem, but only if it could be done in a quick way.

What is the best practice in these situations?

Comment: could you provide a definite example? it's hard to understand what you want to achieve exactly

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I don't know how to put it in a simple and short example. In all web pages there are many elements that change or are created using JS instead of adding manually and directly to the DOM. That's to avoid adding repetitive elements and content manually and also the ability to change the appearance of some content on the whole website by changing only the main script instead of each element directly.

Comment: ... In my current project because of uncertainty on how to show some content (eg. as list or table, as details, summary tags or in simple paragraphs, and many others) it turns to a problem.
I have created a simple HTML file with specific classes and for example instead of creating details, summary tags directly in the HTML file, I am creating it using JS, but initial preparation of the web page takes time.

Comment: ... It could be done to split the script into initial preparation js file and second script file for the other scripts and I supposed there should be a way to execute the first file once and use the resulting DOM with the second file for the website, but I couldn't find a simple and quick way to do this.

Comment: I have no clue what you want. Maybe try to eplain again?